# Inverse Laplace transform of $\exp(-s)F(s)$

Tags: laplace-transform

$$y(s)=1/s - 1/s^2 + \exp(-s)\cdot(1/s^2)$$
I'm struggling with $$\exp(-s)\cdot(1/s^2)$$
formulas: $$f(t-1)u(t-1)\to \exp(-s)F(s)$$
But $$f(t)=t\cdot u(t)$$
is this true:
inverse Laplace transform of $$\exp(-s)F(s)=(t-1)u(t-1)u(t-1)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply:
$$\mathcal{L^{-1}} \left (e^{-s}\dfrac 1 {s^2} \right)=u(t-1)(t-1)$$
Since you have that:
$$\mathcal{L^{-1}} \left (e^{-cs} F(s)\right)=u(t-c)f(t-c)$$

Comment: hmmmm , but what is my mistake ?

Comment: Why do you write twice $u(t-1)$ ? @Hasan

Comment: because first u(t-1) related to F(s) while the second one related to the formula u(t-1)f(t-1) --- exp(-s)F(s)

Comment: Well it's not correct...The function is evaluated at $t-c$ @Hasan

Comment: The inverse laplace transform of $1/s^2$ is $t$ then you evaluate it at $t-1$ so it's just $t-1$ @Hasan

Comment: but why we write f(t)=tu(t)

Comment: Thats correct. But here you have the expnonential $e^{-cs}$ @Hasan So you have $u(t-1)f(t-1)$

Comment: is this special  case? or we always take f(t) without u(t)?

Comment: You take the formula at $t-1$ so evaluate $tu(t)$ at $t-1$ you get the correct answer $(t-1)u(t-1)$  @Hasan

Comment: You just use the same formula but apply the shift theorem @hasan

Comment: clear, thank you